# Проблемы с вопроизведением звукового файла на странице

Tags: javascript

Мне нужно реализовать звук при заходе на страницу
у меня в папке sounds файл sound.mp3

в хедере моего html файла у меня вот это

```
<script src="script.js"></script>
<audio id="audio" src="sounds/sound.mp3"></audio>
```

в джс файле

```
let myAudio = document.getElementById("audio");
myAudio.play()
```

Мне пишет на странице

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'play')

Comment: Потому что скрипт срабатывает раньше загрузки разметки.

Comment: а как это исправить